# Gradiente en CSS no ocupa el alto completo de la pantalla

Tags: css

Tengo este problema: se ve una parte sin *gradient* en la parte de abajo de mi pantalla. No sé cómo quitarlo, lo intenté con `margin` pero lo deja feo cuando lo paso a vista de teléfono-tablet. ¿Me pueden ayudar?

Éste es mi código HTML (para ver el error hay que darle al botón de "Página Completa"):

```css
body 
{
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#D10000,black);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#D10000,black);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D10000,black);
  background: linear-gradient(#D10000,black);
}

.contrast-color
{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-shadow: 4px 4px black;
}

.mih1 { font-size: 40px;
  color: white; }

.myh1 { font-size: 40px;
  color: black; }

.mybutton
{
  color: black;
  border: 2px solid #D10000x|;
  padding: 70px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin: 2px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition-duration:0.5s;
  transition-duration:0.5s
}

.mybutton:hover
{
  background-color: #D10000;
  color: black;
  -webkit-transition-duration:0.5s;
  transition-duration:0.5s
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Alta de calificaciones online</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Mis datos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cambiar contraseña</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Salir</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-6 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-lg-offset-3">
      <h1 class="text-center mih1">Bienvenido</h1>
      <h1 class="text-center myh1"> Daniel <small>Becerril López</small></h1><br>
      <button class="mybutton">Asentar calificaciones</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ésta es la imagen que me está saltando:

[image: Problema con la parte inferior de la pantalla]

Comment: Pues la de abajo, la que no tiene el efecto de gradiant

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: Es un color degradado de rojo a negro, yo esperaba en la parte de abajo totalmente negro, obviamente que se venga degradando de rojo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta configurando tu CSS y añadiendo las siguientes cosas:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
```

Y listo, todo quedará como tu lo deseas :)

```css
html, body{
  height:100%;
 }

body {
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#D10000,black);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(#D10000,black);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D10000,black);
   background: linear-gradient(#D10000,black);
   margin:0px !important;
 }
```

¡Cualquier duda, comentamela! Con gusto te ayudaré, saludos! :D

Comment: Funcionó perverso! Gracias